# Persistence after minikube restart?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm experimenting with minikube (v1.18.1) to learn Kubernetes better.

My pods use persistent volumes and this works fine until I stop and start minikube again. The volumes use local storage in the Minikube VM in /data. In /data I have 3 subdirectories, 1 for each pod.

On [Persistent Volumes](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#:%7E:text=minikube%20is%20configured%20to%20persist,from%20other%20directories%20on%20reboots.&text=You%20can%20also%20achieve%20persistence,in%20a%20mounted%20host%20folder.) I'm reading:

> minikube is configured to persist files stored under the following directories, which are made in the Minikube VM (or on your localhost if running on bare metal). You may lose data from other directories on reboots.

/data is one of those directories, that's why I chose it for my persistent volumes.

Still, the directories disappear upon restart. Am I doing something wrong or am I not understading this correctly?